# Android Send ParseObject to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, serialization, parse-platform

I have a ParseObject I want to send to another activity :

```
public class HWMMatch extends ParseObject implements Serializable{

    public HWMMatch(){ }

    public ParseUser GetUser1() {
        return (ParseUser)getParseObject("user1");
    }
    public void SetUser1(ParseUser user) {
        put("user1", user);
    }

    public ParseUser GetUser2() {
        return (ParseUser)getParseObject("user2");
    }
    public void SetUser2(ParseUser user) {
        put("user2", user);
    }
}
```

In MyActivity1.java

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity2.class);
myIntent.putExtra("match", match);
startActivity(myIntent);

// Here match.getParseObject("user1") is defined
```

But in my MyActivity2.java

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Serializable s = intent.getExtras().getSerializable("match");
if(s != null)
   this.match = (Match) s;

// Here match.getParseObject("user1") is null
```

How can I send a ParseObject from one activity to another one ?

Thanks,

Comment: In Android should use Parcelable instead of Serializable. Try this https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin

Comment: try intent.getSerializableExtra("match");

Comment: I have read the android doc about Parcelable (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and it seems to be what i need but in my ParseObject sublass, I don't really have attributes but getters and setters (http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-on-android-just-got-classier/)

Comment: @Johnsmith how about marshal to json string?

Answer (score 2):

You may use Parcelable. Here is a sample

```
public class Match extends ParseObject implements Parcelable {
    private int intItem;
    private String stringItem;

    public Match(Parcel in) {
        this.intItem = in.readInt();
        this.stringItem = in.readString();
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.intItem);
        dest.writeString(this.stringItem);
    }

    public static final Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public Match createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Match(in);
        }

        public Match[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Match[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Just need to add extra things like below.

```
        public Match(Parcel in) {
            this.intItem = in.readInt();
            this.stringItem = in.readString();
        }
        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeInt(this.intItem);
            dest.writeString(this.stringItem);
        }

        public static final Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
            public Match createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Match(in);
            }

            public Match[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Match[size];
            }
        };
```

Comment: I have read this about Parcelable but in my ParseObject sublass, I don't really have attributes but getters and setters .. I have updated my Post.

Comment: your ParseUser class should also implement Parcelable

Comment: I don't really udnerstand your edited answer, I don't know how to implements the writeToParcel() and Match(Parcel in) methods because I don't use any attributes ..

Comment: can you upload your ParseUser class?

Comment: The ParseUser class is the class of Parse SDK (http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html)

Comment: I got it now. You are using another library. So it will be very hard to implement the Parcelable interface. So you may define a public static member in "MyActivity2.java" or somewhere else and before calling  "MyActivity2" activity you should set the value to that variable. After using the member variable you can set it to null to avoid inconvenience. If you didn't understand my comment, let me know.

Comment: Yes, after reading a lot about this on google, I think I have to write my own class to make a ParseObject serializable and It should probably take a long time. The best solution is maybe to use a static variable or implement a singleton class where I would able to share my objects. Thanks for your help anyway .. and your time !

Answer (score 2):

With the [current version of Parse SDK for Android](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android) 1.19.0 ParseObject already implements Parcelable which means you can simply do:

Current activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PARSE_OBJECT_EXTRA", parseObject);
startActivity(intent);
```

Next Activity

```
ParseObject parseObject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("PARSE_OBJECT_EXTRA");
```