# I want to send parseobject in bundle to different activity how to perform this

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I want to send the *Parse-object* to different activity. How can I perform this?

I'm trying this to put the data gives error:

```
Bundle data=new Bundle();
ParseObject obj=new ParseObject("abc");
data.putSerializable("data",obj);
```

Comment: it says that the parse object is not serializable

Comment: then make it serializable/Parcelable in android

Comment: it is parseobject which is provided by parse sdk how can we convert it

Comment: use sharedPrefrence instead

Answer (score 1):

As you are using ParseObject, so I guess it will be very difficult to convert the object to Serializable or Parcelable. In this case, you may define a public static member in your activity or somewhere else and before calling another activity you should set the value to that variable. After using the member variable you can set it to null to avoid some side effects.

Please see the below link. Check the comments below the answer there.

[Android Send ParseObject to another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352039/android-send-parseobject-to-another-activity/34352470#34352470)